# how to read xls chart in java?

Tags: java, excel, charts

I am using POI API to read a template n to create an XLS file through java.

I want to get the chart from the template. IS there any way to do so?

Comment: Problem i m facing is i have 5 charts in 1 excel.Now if i want to have first 3 charts,so I delete 4,5 sheet programmatically.All fine.
But if i want to keep sequence like 1, 2, 4, 5 it starts behaving weird.What happen is the chart is still refers the deleted sheet n everything mess up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build the chart into the template it will automatically update when you insert data into the spreadsheet.

If you are wanting to create a chart from scratch I believe that this functionality is not yet available in POI.

from the POI site:

> You can not currently create charts.
>   You can however create a chart in
>   Excel, modify the chart data values
>   using HSSF and write a new spreadsheet
>   out. This is possible because POI
>   attempts to keep existing records
>   intact as far as possible.

[POI Limitations](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/limitations.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can use JFree chart API to create charts in excel.. http://www.programming-free.com/2012/12/create-charts-in-excel-using-java.html

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [Andy Khan's JExcel](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/faq/) can help you.  It's a terrific tool.  I much prefer it to POI.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a way to get a GIF or JPEG? Actuate e.Spreadsheet can create images from Excel charts and ranges, but it's expensive (I worked there until 2002 but have no affiliation now).

Answer (score 0):

```
// officetools.jar available at http://www.dancrintea.ro/xls-to-pdf/

import officetools.OfficeFile;

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(”test.xls”));

OfficeFile f = new OfficeFile(fis, ”localhost”, ”8100″, false);

// read a column
for (int i=0; i<=99; i++)
    System.out.println(f.getCell(1,i));
```